# Multiple Spinner in a Recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with 11-row data items. I need to fix two spinners in each row. That the second spinner data should be dependent on the first Spinner data changes. While I'm making new entry data loaded correctly. When I came to edit the first spinner data loading correctly done and already existing data was fixed correctly. **But in the second spinner, it shows the data of the last loaded item. i.e. Last row (11th row) spinner data has been set in all the second spinners.** How to solve this?

Shown below code is under onBindViewHolder() method in recyclerViewAdapter

```java
 fortnightLookupList = gCache.getFortNightLookup();



        for(int i = 0; i<fortnightLookupList.size(); i++){
            funtioningSpinnerList.add(fortnightLookupList.get(i).getFunctioning());
        }
reasoningAdapter =
    new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, funtioningSpinnerList);
reasoningAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
holder.functioningSpinner.setAdapter(reasoningAdapter);

if (entryStatus.equals(Constants.NEW)) {
    holder.functioningSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView . OnItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos > 0) {
                remoteLocationEntryModelData.get(position).checkList =
                    funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos);
                //loadScoreSpinner(funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos), holder, position);

                scoreList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < fortnightLookupList.size(); i++) {
                    if (fortnightLookupList.get(i).getFunctioning().equals(funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos)) ) {
                        scoreList.add(fortnightLookupList.get(i).getScore());
                    }
                }

                scoreAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoreList);
                scoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                holder.scoreSpinner.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);

            } else {
                remoteLocationEntryModelData.get(position).checkList = "$";
                scoreList.clear();
                scoreList.add(0, "---- select ----");
                scoreAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoreList);
                scoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                holder.scoreSpinner.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

} else if (entryStatus.equals(Constants.EDIT)) {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty( String.valueOf( editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getLogId() ) ) ) {
        remoteLocationEntryModelData.get(position).logId =
            editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getLogId();
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getRemarks())) {
        holder.remarksEdt.setText(editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getRemarks());
    }



    holder.functioningSpinner.setSelection(
        funtioningSpinnerList.indexOf(
            editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getCheckList()
        )
    );

    holder.functioningSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView . OnItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos > 0) {
                remoteLocationEntryModelData.get(position).checkList =
                    funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos);
                //loadScoreSpinner(funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos), holder, position);

                scoreList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < fortnightLookupList.size(); i++) {
                    if (fortnightLookupList.get(i).getFunctioning()
                            .equals(funtioningSpinnerList.get(pos))
                    ) {
                        scoreList.add(fortnightLookupList.get(i).getScore());
                    }
                }

                scoreAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoreList);
                scoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                holder.scoreSpinner.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);

                //holder.scoreSpinner.setSelection(scoreList.indexOf(editList.getDescriptions().get(position).getScore()));

            } else {
                remoteLocationEntryModelData.get(position).checkList = "$";
                scoreList.clear();
                scoreList.add(0, "---- select ----");
                scoreAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoreList);
                scoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                holder.scoreSpinner.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

*Note* **While I debug it step by step it is working correctly, but not when during run**

**Current Output**
[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: If I understand correct you have a RecyclerView where every item has two Spinners inside the item with 2 ArrayAdapters attached to them, right? Can you share more information on where do you get your lists for populating the ArrayAdapters of both Spinners?

Comment: YEs you are correct @hardartcore  .... The arrayadapters are in the name of **reasoningAdapter** & **scoreAdapter** you can find those.

Comment: What about the `funtioningSpinnerList` ? Where does it come from? Can you share the code where you are getting this list?

Comment: its just above reasoning adapter. Like below 
`fortnightLookupList = gCache.getFortNightLookup();  
 for(int i = 0; i<fortnightLookupList.size(); i++){
            funtioningSpinnerList.add(fortnightLookupList.get(i).getFunctioning());
        }`

Comment: It's better to post that to the main answer, but I think the problem is the way this list is populated.

Comment: If you use one array list for both spinner it might work.

Comment: I see in your code where you call `functioningSpinner.setSelection()` , but not `scoreSpinner.setSelection()`.  This seems to be a critical omission.  Its also not clear what `entryStatus` is ... a more complete code snapshot would be helpful

Comment: @CSmith its there as commented, but if not so the default 0th position value will be displayed right? in every spinner it is showing.

Answer (score 1):

You save `scoreList` in a global variable and **never** redefines this value

In `holder.functioningSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` you makes `scoreList.clear()`

with always same line you set **same** `List` reference to **all** adapters in `new ArrayAdapter<>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoreList)`

with `scoreList.clear()` you removes data in **all** adapters and **adds** new values.

=> is the reason, why you see the data of last item in all list items

> Note While I debug it step by step it is working correctly, but not
> when during run

Reason for it is:

- in debug mode you are *slow*. there everything comes step by step.
- in real execution everything happens in some milliseconds

**HOW TO SOLVE**

Possibility 1. recreate the list instead of clear data. You make already always `new ArrayAdapter`, why you store `scoreList` instance globally?

Possibility 2. Make a holder as own class and everything you do in `onBindViewHolder` make in a holder class.

Example:

generate base holder class

```
public abstract class BaseRecyclerBindingHolder<Item> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public BaseRecyclerBindingHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void configureView(Item item);
}
```

and base adapter class

```
public abstract class BaseRecyclerBindingAdapter<Item, Holder extends BaseRecyclerBindingHolder<? super Item>, ItemBinding extends ViewBinding>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder> {

    // Store a member variable for the items
    protected final List<Item> mItems;

    /**
     * @param items adapter items to show in UI
     */
    public BaseRecyclerBindingAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    /**
     * Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
     *
     * @param parent   container of adapter items
     * @param viewType type of item
     * @return ViewHolder for adapter item
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Inflate the custom layout
        ItemBinding itemView = getLayoutResource(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);

        return getHolder(itemView, viewType);
    }

    /**
     * Involves populating data into the item through holder
     *
     * @param holder   ViewHolder class to construct UI for item
     * @param position item position in adapter
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        Item item = mItems.get(position);

        holder.configureView(item);
    }

    /**
     * @return count of items in adapter
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    /**
     * gets the type of item of specified position in adapter
     *
     * @param position item position
     * @return default 0
     */
    @Override
    public abstract int getItemViewType(int position);

    /**
     * Usually use:
     * ItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
     * To use parents properties of width and height, make this way:
     * ItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
     *
     * @param layoutInflater the inflater to set XMl to view
     * @param parent         container of adapter items
     * @return ViewBinding element with access to all views with IDs in UI
     */
    protected abstract ItemBinding getLayoutResource(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup parent);

    /**
     * based on viewType gets the ViewHolder class for the item
     *
     * @param viewBinding element with access to all views with IDs in UI
     * @param viewType    type of item
     * @return ViewHolder for adapter item
     */
    protected abstract Holder getHolder(ItemBinding viewBinding, int viewType);

    /**
     * @param position item position
     * @return item on specified position in adapter
     */
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * @return list of items in adapter
     */
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }
}
```

now generate specific holder for your purpose

```
public class YourHolderName extends BaseRecyclerBindingHolder<YourHolderItem> {

    private final YourHolderBinding binding;

    // add here more variable that you needs from adapter
    public YourHolderName(YourHolderBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());

        this.binding = binding;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureView(YourHolderItem yourHolderItem) {
        // here comes what you make i your holder
    }
}
```

and at least define adapter that is always super easy and small

```
public class YourAdapterName extends BaseRecyclerBindingAdapter<YourHolderItem, YourHolderName, YourHolderBinding> {

    /**
     * @param yourHolderItem adapter items to show in UI
     */
    // add more parameters if needed
    public YourAdapterName(List<YourHolderItem> yourHolderItems) {
        super(yourHolderItems);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected YourHolderBinding getLayoutResource(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        return YourHolderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected YourHolderName getHolder(YourHolderBinding viewBinding, int viewType) {
        // add more parameters if needed
        return new YourHolderName(viewBinding);
    }
}
```